# Replace values of a dataframe using another dataframe with different size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df1) that contains information about project_id, cost_center and other features:

| project_id | cost_center | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 8575 | 3 |
| 321 | 8597 | 4 |
| 321 | 8597 | 2 |
| Nan | 8522 | 1 |

Sometimes the project_id is not included there, so is Nan, and for these cases I have a "mapping table" (df2) that indicates the project_id that should be associated to that cost center:

| project_id | cost_center |
| --- | --- |
| 832 | 8522 |

So in my example, I should be able to replace the Nan in df1 for a 832. It means, I should replace the project_id in df1, when the cost_center is in df2.

I tried the following code, but is not working. It says "Length of values (0) does not match length of index (565)" I think because df1 and df2 have different sizes

```
df['project_id'] = df_mapping[df['cost_center'].isin(df_mapping['cost_center'])]['project_id'].values
```

Comment: `df1['project'_id'] = df1['project'_id'].fillna(df1['cost_center'].map(df2.set_index('cost_center')['project_id']))`

Comment: @mozway that should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @alec_djinn probably a duplicate somewhere, but sure, added as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to do this is to merge the 2 DFs and then use fillna() to create a new (output) column. Hope it helps!

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,2,3,None],"center":[5,6,7,8]},index=["a","b","c","d"])
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({"id":[4],"center":[8]},index=["g"])
df_merge = df_1.merge(df_2,on="center",how="outer")
df_merge["id_output"] = df_merge["id_x"].fillna(df_merge["id_y"])
df_merge.drop(["id_x","id_y"],inplace=True, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mapping series and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df1['project_id'] = (df1['project_id']
                     .fillna(df1['cost_center'].map(df2.set_index('cost_center')['project_id']),
                             downcast='infer'
                            )
                    )
```

output:

```
   project_id  cost_center  month
0         101         8575      3
1         321         8597      4
2         321         8597      2
3         832         8522      1
```

Comment: can you explain the downcast='infer', I haven't find documentation about it, and this doesn't seem to be working for me, I'm trying to understand why

Comment: @Stephany this is optional, just to convert the floats automatically to integers (downcasting) if no value has a decimal part

Comment: @Stephany there is no reason why this approach shouldn't work. Can you provide an example for which it fails for you?

Comment: it doesn't replace the Nan values. i'm thinking maybe it has something to do with the data types, in my df1 cost_center is int32 and project_id is object, whereas in df2 both columns are int64, do you think this could be the reason why is not working?

Comment: There is no NaN in your example, can you provide a representative minimal example as DataFrame constructor? And yes, mapping/merging requires the same type (float/int is fine but not numeric/string).